# Rotation: I receive the error "wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, rotation

I have found some similar questions on stackoverflow, but they can not solve my question. The fist time when I do rotation , I receive the error "wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003" and it will be blocked for one or two seconds to print the new view on the new orientation, my code is as below:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:    (NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (isLandScape) {
        [self toHorizontalBrowserView];
    } else {
        [self toVerticalBrowserView];
    }
}

- (void)toHorizontalBrowserView
{
    [horizontalBrowserViewController viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self.activeViewController viewWillDisappear:YES];
    [self.activeViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [_viewController.centerView insertSubview: horizontalBrowserViewController.view atIndex:0];
    [self.activeViewController viewDidDisappear:YES];
    [horizontalBrowserViewController viewDidAppear:YES];
    self.activeViewController = horizontalBrowserViewController;
}

- (void)toVerticalBrowserView
{    
    [verticalPhotoBrowserViewController viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self.activeViewController viewWillDisappear:YES];
    [self.activeViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [_viewController.centerView insertSubview:verticalPhotoBrowserViewController.view atIndex:0];
    [self.activeViewController viewDidDisappear:YES];
    [verticalPhotoBrowserViewController viewDidAppear:YES];
    _activeViewController = verticalPhotoBrowserViewController;
}
```

What is the cause of this problem? How to fix it?

Comment: You should not need to call the viewWillAppear: and viewWillDisappear: methods on your own

Comment: I have tried.But it did not solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in the past. I think the problem is that you are updating/changing the view stack while it's going to be animated. Try commenting out the bits where you are removing and inserting sub-views.